# GPS GPRS, how to receive and process live data

Tags: php, sql, gps, gprs, gpx

I have a GPS with a GPRS with an active SIM card. How do I go about directing the GPRS data to a specific website (IP port_ I believe port 3500 is used). I do not know how to acquire the GPS/GPRS data transmission and do not know how (or what should be done) to process the incoming data.

I am not familiar with the route the GPRS data goes and how to acquire and process it. I assume it would need HTML/XML. I would like to process in real time.

Also what format would a GPS normally send data? GPX, csv?

Comment: I know this is a silly question, but have you consulted the User's Manual or Manufacturer to get further details on how the GPS will communicate? They'll be in the best position to advise how their unit will work, then you can build a solution to interface with it.

Answer (score 2):

I can't be much help with your first question, but as for your second question;
Most GPS's will send information in a format call NMEA. It is a series of text sentences one after the other sent serially.

The sentences will look somethink like this:-

```
$GPGGA,092750.000,5321.6802,N,00630.3372,W,1,8,1.03,61.7,M,55.2,M,,*76
$GPGSA,A,3,10,07,05,02,29,04,08,13,,,,,1.72,1.03,1.38*0A
$GPGSV,3,1,11,10,63,137,17,07,61,098,15,05,59,290,20,08,54,157,30*70
$GPGSV,3,2,11,02,39,223,19,13,28,070,17,26,23,252,,04,14,186,14*79
$GPGSV,3,3,11,29,09,301,24,16,09,020,,36,,,*76
```

Not pretty, but they work quite well. The systems on the bridge of a ship use this format to pass information between each other.

You will find more information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183) and [here](http://www.nmea.org/)

If you only want to pick out one or two sentence types, it shouldn't be too difficult. I think the hardest part will be actually interfacing with the GPS to allow you to receive the sentences in the first place.