# M2M vechile/mobile tracing

Tags: java, m2m

i am going to create a server application where i can see the details of my vehciles/mobiles location. I am new to this concept.i want to know that what type of data that hardware(installed on vehciles) will send to server.i mean is it SMS or something else?
and how can i fetch that data at my server?

Comment: I would ask the suppliers of the hardware. If they don't know, no one does. ;)

Comment: suppose they r sending GPRS data..how will u parse/fetch this data ?

Comment: I would parse the data as text like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619914/gps-gprs-how-to-receive-and-process-live-data

Comment: @peterLawrey - thnx once again.... +1  :)